# Disable Eclipse Highlight on Hover

Tags: eclipse-cdt, highlight

I am using Eclipse.

I have opened a project that contains errors.  Here is an example of the errors:

[image: Example of Errors]

When I hover over the symbol on the left to get more information, I get a dialogue box and the error is automatically highlighted, like this:

[image: Highlighting Error on Hover]

When I click away from the error, the highlighting still persists, like this:

[image]

This will happen for multiple errors, Like this:

[image]

I would like to disable this feature.  How would I do so?

For further information, I am using:
Eclipse Version 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

Operating System is:
centos-release-7-7.1908

The theme is what the IDE defaulted to upon first execution, pictured here:

[image: Default Theme]

Upon Changing the theme to "classic" the issue persists, but with different syntax highlighting:

[image: Different syntax highlighting, same behavior]

I have scraped through all settings pertaining to syntax highlighting in the IDE.  I recognize that the theme displayed as the default theme was pertaining to window coloring as well.  When changed, it still did modify the colors for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Did you check the preferences (`Window > Preferences`)? You might be able to disable it from `General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts` or `C/C++ > Editor`.

Comment: Is this the current Eclipse version 2019-12? Is this the default Eclipse dark theme or did you installed a dark theme plug-in for that? Can you reproduce this issue in the default light theme?

Comment: I included further information about my build and theme management.  I have also scraped through all of the color settings (syntax and otherwise) that I could find.  I wasn't able to identify the problem after referencing the 'Help' built into Eclipse.  Further internet searching also has (thus far) remained a fruitless endeavor.

Comment: You need to check about c++ annotations in the preferences

Comment: Is there any further guidance you can give in regard to "c++ annotations"?  I've searched the settings and can't quite seem to find one that has the desired effect.